# Remote base identification

Tags: united-states, legal, remote-control

I have a remote base where stations can log in with DTMF touch pad.

Does this remote base transmitter need to send out a CW ID?

Comment: Stations log in...to do what?

Comment: To talk on the remote base you log in through DTMF on a repeater up at the site of the remote base or through the internet.

Comment: The reason for login is simply to prevent stations who don't have the license class to operate on a frequency to be transmitting where they shouldn't

Comment: Does it transmit? If it transmits, it must identify.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that according to §97.3, logging in to a remote base through the Internet is considered remote control.  Therefore, the amateur logging in is the control operator, and the normal identification rules apply.  The base does not need to identify separately.

That said, if there's a repeater linked in to the system, such that transmissions are automatically rebroadcast on a different frequency, I think that repeater would need to auto-identify as per usual.  [This site](http://www.w3beinformed.org/id43.html) also indicates (search for 'remote base' within that page) that you'd need to approve this entire setup (a remote base accessed through an otherwise publicly-available repeater) with your local frequency coordinator.

Comment: So I run a DTMF command and now the repeater is linked into the remote. The repeater identifies as usual. Does the remote also need to identify because now it is considered automatic? If I choose to log in on the internet it is considered remote however and It does not have to ID in that case?

Comment: If you're controlling a remote base via the Internet, you are the control operator, and you must identify as normal.  Your base does not need to identify, because it is not under automatic control.

Comment: Is a remote base under automatic control if it is connected to a repeater, however?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the repeater would need to identify as per normal, but the base would not.  Again, you should check with your frequency coordinator on this.